# Hibernate entity cascade deletion parent or child

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, cascade

I have got some problem about "cascade",
in my project I have got category class and each class can be parent or child.But i define in same class which one parent or child.There is a one-to-many relationship between parent and child. This is my entity class

```
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"recipes","categories","parentCategory","childrenCategory"})
@Entity
public class Category implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String categoryName;

    private String categoryDescription;

    private String categoryUrl;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentCategory",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Category> childrenCategory = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToOne
    private Category parentCategory;

    private boolean menuActive;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "categories")
    Set<Recipe> recipes = new HashSet<>();

    public Category addChildren(Category category){
        this.getChildrenCategory().add(category);
        category.setParentCategory(this);
        return this;
    }

}
```

my question is that ; 
When i deleted child category not problem its success.I can not delete the parent category if the parent category has got children.

**Error Message;**

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["FKBPI63NYEL12J6UG0D7S6BUAKX: PUBLIC.CAT_RECIPE FOREIGN KEY(CATEGORY_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.CATEGORY(ID) (5)"; SQL statement:
>   delete from category where id=? [23503-197]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

How can i delete parent category ?

**SOLUTION**

```
public void removeChildren(Category childCategory){
    childCategory.setParentCategory(null);
}
```

and you can call

> category.get().getChildrenCategory().forEach(category.get()::removeChildren);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bidirectional relationship. So you will need to remove association from both sides. Something like this:

```
public void removeChildren(Category childCategory){
    this.getChildrenCategory().remove(childCategory);
    childCategory.setParentCategory(null);
}
```

Then

`parentCategory.getSubCategories().forEach(parentCategory::remove);`

Now you can remove the `parentCategory`.

Comment: for example in this method : parentCategory has got three subCat when i was iterate with for loop first iteration is okey but second throws null exception ?

Comment: i fixed it , this solution sould be ;

public void removeChildren(Category childCategory){
    childCategory.setParentCategory(null);
}

thank you